# Jquery Blueimp File Upload, - image orientation straight out of camera.. not rotating

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

im not a coder so apologies, but looking for some help for my coder who is building a project for me..

It's an image hosting and gallery, and the Blimp Jquery uploader is what we're using to get the images in and to S3..

one snag is, if a jpeg has been through Lightroom or an image editor, and saved like the first image you see it shows correctly, however if the jpeg is uploaded straight out of camera it stays in the rotation of the camera sensor..

I've researched and found this is something to do with the exif date which holds info on the camera orientation,( 1 -8 depending upon how it was held) but it seems the uploader cant translate and auto rotate the images it needs to unlike image editors/viewers...?

Any ideas?

[screen shot of  2 uploaded files, before and after image editor save.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27HBr.jpg)

Comment: I don't think the file uploader is the issue, but probably the image viewer. What program displays the images?